# Exploding a URL

Tags: php

What am I doing wrong? I currently have the following code below and I am trying to just get the secondary url which links to the direct MP3 path.

```
$date = $html2->find('strong > a',0);
$explode = explode ("http://www.example.com/?dl_name=", $date->href);
print $explode;
```

It returns *ARRAY*.

Comment: [explode function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php). first param is the delimiter.

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you resolve this with `str_replace`:

```
$secondary_url = str_replace("http://www.example.com/?dl_name=", '', $date->href);
```

You will get the rest of this string in `$secondary_url`.

Reference: [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Answer (score 3):

explode returns an array of strings, try using print_r($explode) and then use $explode[0], $explode[1]...